# Find K-nearest neighbour with custom distance metric

Tags: python, scikit-learn, distance-functions, k-nearest-neighbour

I am working on finding similar items. Each item has a representation as a vector of features. Instead of using one kind of distance metric for each feature like "ëuclidean" distance. I want a mixture of distance . For example euclidean for some features and jaccard for some features.

Is it possible to do in `scikit-learn` in `python`

Comment: It is definitely possible. Scikit-Learn has a [KDTree class](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.KDTree.html) which lets your specify a custom [DistanceMetric](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.DistanceMetric.html) object to define the distance metric you need.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes it is. As stated by @Jeremie Clos, you can specify a custom metric. From the [official documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.NearestNeighbors.html#sklearn.neighbors.NearestNeighbors):

```
class sklearn.neighbors.NearestNeighbors(n_neighbors=5, radius=1.0, 
    algorithm='auto', leaf_size=30, 
    metric='minkowski', p=2, metric_params=None, n_jobs=1, **kwargs)
```

> metric : string or callable, default ‘minkowski’ metric to use for
>   distance computation.
>
> Any metric from scikit-learn or
>   scipy.spatial.distance can be used.
>
> If metric is a callable function,
>   it is called on each pair of instances (rows) and the resulting value
>   recorded. The callable should take two arrays as input and return one
>   value indicating the distance between them.
>
> This works for Scipy’s
>   metrics, but is less efficient than passing the metric name as a
>   string. Distance matrices are not supported.
>
> Valid values for metric
>   are: from scikit-learn:
>
> [‘cityblock’, ‘cosine’, ‘euclidean’, ‘l1’,
>   ‘l2’, ‘manhattan’]
>
> from scipy.spatial.distance:
>
> [‘braycurtis’,
>   ‘canberra’, ‘chebyshev’, ‘correlation’, ‘dice’, ‘hamming’, ‘jaccard’,
>   ‘kulsinski’, ‘mahalanobis’, ‘matching’, ‘minkowski’, ‘rogerstanimoto’,
>   ‘russellrao’, ‘seuclidean’, ‘sokalmichener’, ‘sokalsneath’,
>   ‘sqeuclidean’, ‘yule’]
>
> See the documentation for
>   scipy.spatial.distance for details on these metrics.